# How to create a pie chart with color and pattern in SPSS

Tags: pie-chart, spss

I want to create a colored and additional pattern, pie chart with GGRAPH\GPL. The function of the pattern is to visualize the major category to which the respective category belongs to.

With the SPSS Chart Builder I can only create a colored or a patterned pie chart.

The relevant `ELEMENT` Statement looks as follows:

```
ELEMENT: interval.stack(position(summary.percent(COUNT))), color(myvar))
```

Or:

```
ELEMENT: interval.stack(position(summary.percent(COUNT))), texture.pattern(myvar))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the Syntax created for the colored pie chart you can add the texture by simply adding the `texture.pattern(myVar)` function into the Element statement:

```
  ELEMENT: interval.stack(position(summary.percent(COUNT))), color(krwirtsek_kombi), texture.pattern(krwirtsek_kombi))
```

You can specify the color and pattern by using a template or via the `map`-function inside the scale statment:

```
SCALE: cat(aesthetic(aesthetic.color.interior), map(("<catvalue>", color."<rgb>"),  ...)
SCALE: cat(aesthetic(aesthetic.texture.pattern), map(("<catvalue>", texture.pattern.<patternconstant>), ...)
```

However when combining the color() and the `texture.pattern()` functions in the ELEMENT Statement and the tinkering with oder GPL-funtions, the results of these other functions might get odd (see [this question about category order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55956990/what-does-it-need-to-specify-the-category-order-in-a-colored-and-patterned-pie-c/55957088#55957088)).